# VueJS 3 : Add event listener through js code

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, vuejs3

Is there an option to add a listener through js code in Vue3?

Inside the child I'm emitting an event like this:

```
this.$emit('someEvent', msg);
```

And in the parent I'm listening to it like this:

```
<some-child v-on:someEvent="handleSomeEvent" />
```

However I'm looking for a way to start listening to the event like this:

```
this.$refs.someChild.$on('someEvent', (evt) => {});

// or 

this.$refs.someChild.addEventlistener('someEvent', (evt) => {});
```

Comment: Hey, I want to achieve the same but cannot find a solution in the vue documentation. Did you find a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure where I needed this for anymore but normally I post  a solution or workaround when I find one. Since I didn't do that here there probably isn't one :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to dynamically listen to different events? In that case

In the parent

```html
<some-child v-on="myEvents" />
```

```js
data(){
    return{
        myEvents:{
            someEvent:(evt)=>{console.log(evt)},
            someOtherEvent:(evt)=>{console.log(evt)},
        }
    }
}
```

It is equivalent as

```html
<some-child @someEvent="..." @someOtherEvent="..." />
```

Now you can add new listener to `myEvents` or change existing ones by setting `this.myEvents.someEvent = myNewCallback`

Comment: How does this solution would look like in class style syntax?